# Node.js web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm new to node.js and any help would be much appreciated.

I've been given the task scrape product names and prices from a website - in this example a record store (http://www.recordstore.co.uk/recordstore/New-Releases/).

When I run the following code to gather product prices 40 undefined values are returned but not 40 prices. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
    prices = [];

request('http://www.recordstore.co.uk/recordstore/New-Releases/', function(err, resp, body){
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var price = $('dl', '#col2').each(function(){
            var price = $(this).attr('dd.price');
            prices.push(price);
        });

        console.log(prices);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the prices from the `dd` elements with the `class="price"`:

```
$('dl', '#col2').each(function() {
    var price = $('dd.price', this).text();
    prices.push(price);
});
```